# PHP preg_match_all trouble

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have written a regular expression that I tested in rubular.com and it returned 4 matches. The subject of testing can be found here http://pastebin.com/49ERrzJN and the PHP code is below. For some reason the PHP code returns only the first 2 matches. How to make it to match all 4? It seems it has something to do with greediness or so.

```
$file = file_get_contents('x.txt');
preg_match_all('~[0-9]+\s+(((?!\d{7,}).){2,20})\s{2,30}(((?!\d{7,}).){2,30})\s+([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\s+(F|M)\s+(.{3,25})\s+(((?!\d{7,}).){2,50})~', $file, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($m as $v) echo 'S: '. $v[1]. '; N: '. $v[3]. '; D:'. $v[7]. '<br>';
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract?

Comment: Isn't rubular.com for **Ruby**?

Comment: @Druzion: name, surname, DOB, sex most of all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is very slooooooow. After trying it on regex101.com, I found it would timeout on PHP (but not JS, for whatever reason). I'm pretty sure the timeout happens at around 50,000 steps. Actually, it makes sense now why you're not using an online PHP regex tester.

I'm not sure if this is the source of your problem, but [there is a default memory limit in PHP:](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

> memory_limit [default:] "128M"
>
> [history:] "8M" before PHP 5.2.0, "16M" in PHP 5.2.0

If you use the `m`ultiline modifier (I assume that `preg_match_all` essentially adds the `g`lobal modifier), you can use this regex that only takes 1282 steps to find all 4 matches:

`^ [0-9]+\s+(((?!\d{7,}).){2,20})\s{2,30}(((?!\d{7,}).){2,30})\s+([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\s+(F|M)\s+(.{3,25})\s+(((?!\d{7,}).){2,50})`

Actually, there are only 2 characters that I added. They're at the beginning, the anchor `^` and the literal space.

Comment: thanks, adding the 2 characters and using m modifier did the job

Comment: Patterns problems have nothing to do with PHP memory limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to write a long pattern, the first thing to do is to make it readable. To do that, use the verbose mode (x modifier) that allows comments and free-spacing, and use named captures.

Then you need to make a precise description of what you are looking for:

- your target takes a whole line => use the anchors `^` and `$` with the modifier m, and use the `\h` class *(that only contains horizontal white-spaces)* instead of the `\s` class.
- instead of using this kind of inefficient sub-patterns `(?:(?!.....).){m,n}` to describe what your field must not contain, describe what the field can contain.
- use atomic groups `(?>...)` when needed instead of non-capturing groups to avoid useless backtracking.
- in general, using precise characters classes avoids a lot of problems

pattern:

```
~
^ \h*+ # start of the line
# named captures                            # field separators
(?<VOTERNO>     [0-9]+                     )  \h+
(?<SURNAME>     \S+ (?>\h\S+)*?            )  \h{2,}
(?<OTHERNAMES>  \S+ (?>\h\S+)*?            )  \h{2,}
(?<DOB>         [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} )  \h+
(?<SEX>         [FM]                       )  \h+
(?<APPID_RECNO> [0-9A-Z/]+                 )  \h+
(?<VILLAGE>     \S+ (?>\h\S+)*             ) 
\h* $  # end of the line
~mx
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ6rG0/1)

If you want to know what goes wrong with a pattern, you can use the function [`preg_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php)